# Bootstrap-sass not working within Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

I am attempting to contribute to a rails app which has the following in the gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '>= 3.2'
```

It seems like everything works correctly in my layouts with the exception of columns:

`<div class="col-md-6">` has no effect whatsoever on the content that it wraps.

However, if I add this line:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

To my `<head>`, the `<div class="col-md-6">` works perfectly but several other bootstrap classes don't work, specifically around the `navbar` I have in place.

How can I get the effect of the above div class without including the following line?

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your gemfile defines: bootstrap 2.3.2.2, and you are using syntax for bootstrap 3.0.0.
Note that the specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example: ~> 2.3.2.2 is identical to >= 2.3.2.2 and < 2.4 ([more info here](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html)).

CSS overrides anything that was written "before" the latest lines, so when you add the link in your layout, the CSS for bootstrap 3.0.0 overrides anything in your assets pipeline. Everything that continues working in your web app was simply not changed between these versions, everything that stops working was changed.

You can get what you want by using the syntax from the [boostrap 2.3.2 refences guide](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/). You will find the default grid system under the scaffolding link.

Answer (score 4):

Did you import the bootstrap mixins? You'd need to add `@import "bootstrap/theme";` to your `application.css.scss` file

Here's a [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/README.md#usage) to that section of the docs.

Also, have you tried the [bootstrap-sass-rails](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails/blob/develop/README.md#bootstrapsassrails) gem instead?

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I have added `@import "bootstrap";` to my `application.css.scss` file, and the bootstrap components seem to work everywhere else. I just created this layout and copied the exact layout of another file, which I know works, but when adding in the above `div class` it doesn't work. It's like whatever version of `bootstrap` my app is using doesn't allow for that class, but when I put in the `link href` tag it does.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: include gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6' and run bundle update

Step 2: in application.js file include 
`//= require bootstrap-sprockets`

Step 3: in css file :
Make sure the file has .scss extension (or .sass for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so rename it:

```
**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**
```

and remove all the lines from that and include

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Step 4:rails run server